# How to iterate over Postgresql rows in a Python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql

I'm writing a script which selects from a DB table and iterates over the rows.

In MySQL I would do:

```
import MySQLdb
db_mysql=MySQLdb.Connect(user=...,passwd=...,db=..., host=...)
cur = db_mysql.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute ("""SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a""")
for row in crs.fetchall () :
     do things...
```

But I don't know how to do it in PostgreSQL.
Basically this question could be how to translate the above MySQL code to work with PostgreSQL.

This is what I have so far (I am using PyGreSQL).

```
import pg
pos = pg.connect(dbname=...,user=...,passwd=...,host=..., port=...)
pos.query("""SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a""")
```

How do I iterate over the query results?

Comment: A two second search in google yield this: http://www.pygresql.org/contents/tutorial.html

Comment: My bad linking to plpgsql docs, but what DB-API module is that? For what I know [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) for example supports cursors nicely.

Comment: I too recommend using `psycopg`. What is this `pg` anyway?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Where do you see there option to do a for loop over the results of query?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala pg is a package for python. You can see it also in the link Loïc Faure-Lacroix gave...  first row there is `from pg import DB`

Comment: @java `for row in crs.fetchall():` in your MySQL code actually does what it says: fetches all. No cursor magic involved other than using one. Your [pg](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/tutorial.html) has the equivalent methods `fetchall`, `fetchone` and `fetchmany`.

Comment: @java the correct answer to my question is *it is from **Pygresql***. I didn't know that. I added the tag for it.

Comment: @java if you look at the tutorial, you'll see the many methods that return a resultset, resultsets are usually list or iterables and can be used in a for loop. The documentation is there to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieved from http://www.pygresql.org/contents/tutorial.html, which you  should read.

```
q = db.query('select * from fruits')
q.getresult()
```

The result is a Python list of tuples, eardh tuple contains a row, you just need to iterate over the list and iterate or index the tupple.

Comment: Can it be changed to a dictonary? So I can access by column names rather than column indxes?

Comment: @java change it to: q.dictresult()

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the same, you must create cursor, call some fetch and iterate just like in MySQL:

```
import pgdb
pos = pgdb.connect(database=...,user=...,password=...,host=..., port=...)
sel = "select version() as x, current_timestamp as y, current_user as z"
cursor = db_conn().cursor()
cursor.execute(sel)
columns_descr = cursor.description
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    x, y, z = row
    print('variables:')
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (x, y, z))
    print('\nrow:')
    print(row)
    print('\ncolumns:')
    for i in range(len(columns_descr)):
        print('-- %s (%s) --' % (columns_descr[i][0], columns_descr[i][1]))
        print('%s' % (row[i]))
    # this will work with PyGreSQL >= 5.0
    print('\n testing named tuples')
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (row.x, row.y, row.z))
```

Comment: it says `AttributeError: cursor` on the first line. pos doesn't have `cursor()` from what I can tell.

Comment: OK. You use classic pygres API. I think it is better to use it's DB API 2.0 interface. To do it you must import `pgdb` and change some names of parameters to `connect()`.

Comment: Will I then be able to access data as : `row['x']` rather than `row[0]`? (Like Dictonary). In MySQL I can do: `connection.cursor(dictionary=True)`  don't know what is the equivelent here.

Comment: I don't think so. It is Python DB-API where you can read column name, type, etc. from `cursor.description`, see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes and my edited code example

Comment: With PyGreSQL >= 5.0 rows are named tuples, so you can use row.x